# How to retrieve command line arguments in AvaloniaUI application?

Tags: c#, .net, avaloniaui

AvaloniaUI version is 11.0

A comment in the application's startup code discourages adding other code.

Initialization code in `Program.cs`:

```
  // Initialization code. Don't use any Avalonia, third-party APIs or any
  // SynchronizationContext-reliant code before AppMain is called: things aren't initialized
  // yet and stuff might break.
  [STAThread]
  public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
      BuildAvaloniaApp()
           .StartWithClassicDesktopLifetime(args);
  }

  // Avalonia configuration, don't remove; also used by visual designer.
  public static AppBuilder BuildAvaloniaApp()
  {
      return AppBuilder.Configure<App>()
                .UsePlatformDetect()
                .WithInterFont()
                .LogToTrace();
  }
```

Is there a way to get command line arguments in another part of the application?

Comment: Only by passing variable args to the other parts of the application.  It is like any other parameter in a method and is put on the execution stack when passed.  So stack variables are only available locally to a method.

Answer (score 1):

Ок. Avalonia has way to pass cli args.

`App.axaml.cs` has method `OnFrameworkInitializationCompleted()`

You need cast `ApplicationLifetime` property to `IClassicDesktopStyleApplicationLifetime` type and use `Args` property.

```
public override void OnFrameworkInitializationCompleted()
{

  if (ApplicationLifetime is IClassicDesktopStyleApplicationLifetime desktop)
  {
    //COMMAND LINE ARGUMENTS HERE
    var args = desktop.Args;

    ...
  }

  base.OnFrameworkInitializationCompleted();
}
```